# One word for light turning on and off regularly

Tags: single-word-requests

When light turns on and off *IRREGULARLY*, the right word is **flicker**. Is there a word for light turning on and off at a regular rate?

Comment: Have you done any research? What did you find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is blinking.

For example, 'The light was blinking as I entered the ....'.

Flickering is not the correct term since it is defined as "moving or shining irregularly or unsteadily" in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flickering).

The word flashing is defined as sudden and intense light. It suitable for warning lights that turns on and off as in [Strobe and Flashing Lights](https://www.grainger.com/category/safety/safety-alarms-and-warnings/strobe-and-flashing-lights).

Winking is more suitable for lights seen at a distance as it means twinkling light.

Comment: I'll have to settle for this if I don't find another word. It's correct, but literary.

Comment: I have heard this word used often. I am surprised it is regarded as literary. Other possibilities are winking (which might be a bit literary) and flashing.

Comment: @Adam You may be confusing "blink" with "twinkle", which is indeed literary. _Blink_ is more ordinary.

Comment: Blinking is certainly not literary and is common in electrics and electronics: if you look on washing machine forums you'll see "What to do about blinking light on my Zanussi?" which is about as far from literary as you can get.

Comment: I disagree about *flash*. At m-w I see "to give off light suddenly or in transient bursts*" Oxford online has" flasher -- an automatic device causing a light to flash on and off rapidly*. Google has for "flash" "(of a light or something that reflects light) shine in a bright but brief, sudden, or intermittent way.
"the lights started flashing""

Comment: I think blinking is literary because it is given in the example in Merriam-Webster dictionary.  'She loves to sit in the dark and watch the lights on the Christmas tree blink in ever-changing patterns'.
Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/blinking.

Comment: Dictionaries give common usage too, otherwise they would be kept in the literary cupboard.

Comment: @StuartF - I wish I had half of your overconfidence. This sense of blink is literary according to every reputable dictionary. You can check it here; the second sense: 
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blink